# One feature1 file unable to run another feature2 file if have json called in feature2 in karate

Tags: karate, intellij-14

**Feature1 path:**
main/feature1

**Feature2 path:**
main/auth/feature2

**JSON file path:**
main/auth/data.json

**Feature2 code:**
Feature: test
Background:
* url baseURL
* def users = read('user.json')

```
  Scenario: Login Admin
    Given path 'user/login'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    And request users
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    * print response
```

**Feature1 code:**\

```
Feature: call test


  Scenario: Run Flow Features Files
    * call read('Auth/feature2.feature')
```

The issue is if I run feature2 from feature1 then its expecting.json file in same directory where feature1 exists

**my POM**

```
 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>        
        <karate.version>1.2.0.RC4</karate.version>
    </properties>    

    <dependencies>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>          
        </plugins>        
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a prefix like `classpath:/some/path/some.feature` or even the `this:` prefix. Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#reading-files